# Как правильно передать значение поля класса в другой класс

Tags: java

**Есть первый класс, в который я хочу передать данные из второго класса.**

```
public class Client extends UserInterfaceClient {
    private PrintWriter writer;
    Socket socket;

    public void setUpConnection (){
        TestActionListener testActionListener = new TestActionListener();
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5052);
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            writer.println(testActionListener.getMessages());
            System.out.print(testActionListener.getMessages());
            writer.flush();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

И вот второй класс из которого я пытаюсь передать значение.

```
public class UserInterfaceClient {
    JTextField outgoing;
    JTextField test;

    public void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        outgoing = new JTextField(20);
        test = new JTextField(10);
        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
        ActionListener actionListener = new TestActionListener();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(400, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        mainPanel.add(sendButton);
        mainPanel.add(outgoing);
        sendButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
    }

    public class  TestActionListener implements ActionListener{
        private String messages;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            messages = outgoing.getText();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
            outgoing.setText("");
            outgoing.requestFocus();
        }
        public String getMessages(){
            return messages;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        new UserInterfaceClient().go();
        new Client().setUpConnection();
    }
}
```

Я понимаю, что до нажатия кнопки поле класса TestActionListener messages - null. В итоге именно это значение передаются через метод в другой класс. Почему так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void setUpConnection (){
    TestActionListener testActionListener = new TestActionListener();
    ...
}
```

Это первый actionListener.

```
public void go(){
    ...
    ActionListener actionListener = new TestActionListener();
    ...
}
```

Это второй actionListener. И после этого вы хотите, чтобы они были одинаковыми? В одном классе вы создаете экземпляр класса `TestActionListener`, в другой вы передаёте уже созданный экземпляр. И тогда всё заработает.

Передавать можно:

1. через конструктор класса
2. через метод класса
3. через абстрактный метод класса. Определив все действия в момент создания.
4. Подписать один из классов на события (аналог `sendButton.addActionListener(actionListener)`);

Comment: Спасибо, если я правильно понял то если передавать через конструктор, то необходимо создать переменную экземпляра класса?
 private TestActionListener actionListener;
и конструктор?
public Client(){
      actionListener = new TestActionListener();
    }
и дальше уже через геттер обращаться к приватному полю?

Я наверное не понимаю, в чём суть, но хотел бы разобраться. Следуя моей логике поле private String messages метода  TestActionListner , принимает значение после нажатия на кнопку.